# Why we do we say אבינו מלכנו on שבת during נעילה?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, yom-kippur

According to the Ashkenazic minhag, why do we say אבינו מלכנו on שבת during נעילה if we don't say it during all other Yom Kippur תפילות?